# MVC Route parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "BlogRoute", // Route name
                 "blog/{action}", // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id="abc" } // Parameter defaults
             );
```

... and have this Index method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            return View((object)id);
        }
```

Is it possible for someone to change that id parameter from "abc" to something else? For example, by appending ?id=somethingElse to the URL? I tried that but it didn't change it. So is it guaranteed that I'll always get "abc" in the Index method?

Basically I need to send a hardcoded string when one route is chosen and I don't want the user to be able to change this string via the URL or any other mechanism. It's like "abc" is a password (it's not but just assume it is). Only the developer is allowed to set this string by editing Global.asax.cs.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a constraint for the id parameter using the regular expression /abc/

Comment: If I do: /blog?id=123 , the parameter that I get on the Index method is still "abc" not "123". I'm wondering if I really need a constraint? Isn't the way I've declared my route already guaranteed that I'll always have id "abc"?

Comment: I didn't notice that {id} was missing in the route definition. You can ignore my previous comment in tht case. I think you should be fine with the route as it is.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed I can also use Data Tokens for what I need.